# How to check if a bigquery day partition is empty

Tags: google-bigquery

To check if a table exists, we can use this query, it's quite cheap:

```
#legacySql
SELECT last_modified_time FROM {dataset}.__TABLES__ WHERE table_id='{table}'
LIMIT 1
```

Is there any similar cheap query to check if a partition is empty?

As I understand, I can use a select with _PARTITIONTIME in where clause but it will end up processing all data in the partition (if it exists) regardless of the limit clause. I've to perform check for the existence of many partitions and it has to be in form of a query and not an API request.

I've cronjobs which may run multiple times but I want to write data to the partition only if it's empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below query is as cheap as $0 so you can safely use this approach to identify number of rows in any partition

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT _PARTITIONTIME AS pt, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourpartitionedtable`
GROUP BY pt  
HAVING pt = TIMESTAMP('2016-12-11')
```

Another option is below - it actually returns 0 if partition is empty and returns count of rows in partition otherwise

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT IFNULL((
    SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourpartitionedtable`
    GROUP BY _PARTITIONTIME HAVING _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2016-11-11')
  ), 0) cnt
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#legacySql
    SELECT 
      partition_id
    FROM 
      [DATASET.TABLE$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]
    WHERE 
      partition_id = "20171224"
```

See for more details: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables

Comment: I believe this has the advantage of distinguishing between empty partitions (returns results) and non-existing partitions (returns no results)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can issue a query dry run to estimate the number of bytes read by the query, without retrieving the real data. You are not charged for a dry run.

You can perform a dry run for a query job by using:

> - The `--dry_run` flag with the `query` command in the `bq` command-line tool
> - The `dryRun` parameter in the job configuration when you use the API or    client libraries

See the document for details: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dry-run-queries#python

This is what I do for my python code:

```py
def dry_query(query: str) -> int:
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(dry_run=True, use_query_cache=False)
    query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)

    return query_job.total_bytes_processed
```